# Keep running golang project even if console closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2, putty

How to keep golang project running even if console (putty) is closed. I have REST API developed in golang and hosted on AWS and using putty to connect and run the project

following command are used to install and run the project ( myapi )

```
go install myapi

myapi
```

when I close putty it stops working.

Comment: You need to look into running the process as a service. It won't be specific to AWS. I'm not sure about the best way to do this with Go, but you might look at this: https://github.com/kardianos/service

Comment: It also isn't specific to Go. It's specific only to the OS - for example, in Linux, this can be as simple as `nohup myapi &` or as complex as full service management using init.d, supervisord, runit, etc.

Comment: You could [immortalize it](https://immortal.run): `immortal myapi`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a number of options to keep your process running. The easiest of which is to use the `nohup` command.

`$ nohup myapi &`

The above command should run your application and print the output to a file called nohup.out. This file will be located in the directory where you run the command. Another option is to use [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki).

If you want to start running your project in a more production ready way, you should look into service managers like [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/).

Comment: screen seems to be working for me but not sure if it has any cons or something I should take care of, can you share your thought on it.

Comment: screen technically works but nohup is a better option if you want something with the same level of simplicity. Answer is right though, if you want production-grade, you want a real service manager like initd/supervisord/systemd/upstart/runit/etc.

Comment: The cons to using screen/tmux/nohup is that they are not easily configured for certain use cases. When running software you have different priorities compared to when developing. E.G.
- Where are my logs?
- How can I limit my programs access on the server/network for security reasons?
- If the server restarts how can I restart my process?
- How can I package my application to make it simple to deploy?
- How can I monitor my application?

An init system (systemd,initd,...) gives you tools to do all the above and more. The more you work with managing software the clearer these uses become

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/)

Run your program as a non-privileged user and use the [setcap](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap) utility to grant it the needed permissions.

For example, to allow binding to a low port number (like 80) run will need to run setcap once on the executable:

`sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /opt/yourGoBinary`

You may need to install setcap: `sudo aptitude install libcap2-bin`

**Alternatively**

Debian comes with a tool called `start-stop-daemon` which is a standard way for starting daemons in `init.d` scripts. It can also also put the process in background for you if the program does not do it on its own. Have a look at the `--background` option.

Use `/etc/init.d/skeleton` as the basis of your init script, but change the `do_start()` function as follows:

```
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
    --background --exec $DAEMON --test > /dev/null \
            || return 1
start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile \
    --background --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_ARGS \
            || return 2
```

Also above added the `--make-pidfile` option which creates the PID file for you.

In case you need to switch to a different user in a secure way, there is also `--chuid` option.

On Ubuntu and RHEL/CentOS/SL 6.X the simplest way is to write an `upstart` job configuration file. Just put `exec /usr/sbin/yourprogram` in the `/etc/init/yourprogram.conf` configuration file. With upstart there is no need to force the program in background. Do not add `expect fork` or `expect daemon` which you need with traditional daemons. With upstart it is better if the process does not fork.